# How to set select option value to null in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have the following markup:

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedCategory" 
     (ngModelChange)="selectCategory($event && $event != 'null' ? $event : null)">

  <option [value]="null">(all categories)</option>
  <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [ngValue]="cat">{{cat.name}}</option>

</select>
```

and in TypeScript:

```
export class MyComp {
    public categories: Category[];
    public selectedCategory: Category;
    public selectCategory(cat: Category) {
        this.selectedCategory = cat;
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

It just doesn't look like the correct way to do it. Is there any other less verbose way to get a default option with a value of null (not 'null')? I can't put the default option in the categories array since it would mess up other code. And I don't mind the `ngModelChange` since I need to run custom code on selection. It's just the `$event && $event != 'null' ? $event: null` part I would like to clean up.

I can't use `[ngValue]` on the default options; it just gives me a value of `0: null` (string). And skip setting value results in binding `selectedCategory=null` not to match the default option leaving the combo box unselected at init.

Answer (score 41):

While Igors solution isn't working quite right for me, here's what I use:

```html
<select [ngModel]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="selectItem($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Don't show</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component()
export class SelectionComponent {
    @Input() items: any[];
    selectedItem: any = null;
    selectItem(item?: any)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

There's two important details to consider here:

1. In the template, make your default option use `null` as `ngModel`, like this: `[ngValue]="null"`. This is to bind a null option.
2. Make sure to assign the `selectedItem` in the component `null`, otherwise it's undefined and your `select` will show as empty / not have the default selection.

Comment: I encountered similiar issue when I have had numeric `ngModel`. Seems to be, [ngValue] preserves numerical type, but [value] doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As of now there is an [open issue in the github repository](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9682) for this.

I found that this can be used to achieve the same thing you have but with slightly less code. It also assumes that you are not using empty string as a possible value but if you are just modify it slightly to take that into account in the conditional statement.

View

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedCategory" 
        (ngModelChange)="selectedCategory = $event ? $event : null">
  <option value="">(all categories)</option>
  <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [ngValue]="cat">{{cat.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Component *no additional logic required*

```
export class MyComp {
    public categories: Category[];
    public selectedCategory: Category;
}
```

**If** you still wanted to `do stuff` (*referring to your code sample*) on model change then the method approach you have would be better suited but if all you wanted to do was set the value to a valid category or `null` if no single category was selected this would make for less code.

Comment: This will cause the dropdown to select an empty item instead of (all categories) item on null

Answer (score 3):

simply use `[value]="undefined"`

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory">
    <option [value]="undefined" disabled hidden>Select...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of categories">{{c}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this not working. I test it but option value set "undefined" in string

Comment: @amir110 Solution for me was to use [ngValue] instead of [value]. However, it is only needed if the option is **not** _disabled_. A reasoning can be found here: https://trungk18.com/experience/angular-select-option-value-ngvalue/

Answer (score 1):

This is the best option I could think of. At least all logic is in the template...

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" (ngModelChange)="selectedCategory = selectedCategory || null">
  <option [ngValue]="null" disabled hidden>Select...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let c of categories">{{c}}</option>
</select>
```